# Tensorflow keras initializers give error even if they work

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've produced this code:

```
def mlp(L, n_list, activation, Cb, Cw):
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    #Creo gli inizializzatori -> oggetti necessari a inizializzare i pesi W (chiamati kernel) e i bias
    kernel_initializers_list = []
 
    for l in range(0, L+1): 
        kernel_initializers_list.append(tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(0, math.sqrt(Cw/n_list[l]), seed = l))
   
    bias_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=math.sqrt(Cb), seed = 100)

    #Aggiungo gli strati al modello: Dense e' il classico strato pieno di neuroni
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_list[1], input_shape=[n_list[0]], use_bias = True, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializers_list[0],
              bias_initializer = bias_initializer))
    for l in range(1, L+1): 
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_list[l+1], activation=activation, use_bias = True, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializers_list[l],
                  bias_initializer = bias_initializer))

    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

It works correctly, but whenever there is `bias_initializer = bias_initializer` in visual studio code the code is red underlined and it tells me:

```
Argument of type "RandomNormal" cannot be assigned to parameter "bias_initializer" of type "str" in function "__init__"
  "RandomNormal" is incompatible with "str"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

What's the problem? I've done the same were done by them [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/)

Comment: This is a false positive in your IDE, not an actual error in the code.